# Seeing huge increase in ssh bruteforce attacks from mass of IPs. Am I being specifically targeted?

Tags: networking, ssh, security

I am suddenly seeing a mass of bruteforce ssh attacks on my personal server.  I am using fail2ban, and the attacks are causing fail2ban to have significant CPU load just to keep up with the banning.  That's how I noticed the attack - because fail2ban kept spiking up to 100% CPU usage.

I have increased ban time, but I am seeing bruteforce attacks come in from a huge mass of IP addresses, presumably through a botnet.

Is this the current state of affairs for all servers in 2020, or am I being specifically targeted?  (though I can't imagine why, there's nothing of value on my server).

I've turned off PasswordAuthentication and now I just see the connect and disconnect, so that's holding them off for now, but it's still using up networking and CPU resources on my server to deal with the attack.

I assume it's not some sort of IP spoofing, since it uses the same IP multiple times until it gets banned.  Not even sure if one can spoof the IP address to sshd.

So the question is - is this normal or do I have reason to believe that someone is intentionally attacking my server specifically?  And follow-up, is there a good way to stop this attack from using up my resources, or should I just let it run it's course until whomever is controlling the botnet figures out that there's no way in?

I cannot use whitelisting on my ssh server because I need to be logged in from multiple locations.

Comment: Consider changing the ssh server port number from the default 22 to a non-default, such as 2222?

Comment: I thought about that, but it seems like such an easy thing to scan for that it only becomes an inconvenience.  It's my next step if they don't shutdown the botnet now that every connection is just getting closed.

Comment: Perhaps another question would be - how much does changing the port number effect frequency of ssh brute force attacks?

Comment: I changed my SSH port from the default and the attacks dropped to zero.  But I never had a targeted attack such as you are describing, just the normal drive-by stuff.

Comment: Yea - can't tell if this is a targeted attack or just an intensification of what we'll be seeing for ssh attacks in the future.  I ended up changing my port and they haven't figured it out yet.  If it comes back then I'll implement port knocking.

Comment: Are you positive that your blocks are working correctly? are the attempts coming from adjacent IPs, such that you could try blocking entire /24s on each attempt?

Comment: The IPs are not adjacent.  My blocks were working, I'd see each IP that was blocked would stop accessing, and I'd just get hit with another one.

Comment: So I changed the port and it went away from a while, but now they've found the port and are back.  Again - is this likely to be some automation that is just trying to brute force everywhere, or is it more likely someone is directly trying to attack my system?